# Where to find android layout xml source code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I would like to create a layout resource which is based on a built-in Android layout. Where can I look up the xml source for this resource?
When I press cmd+B in Android Studio, I end up in R.java, which only shows me the int value.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Comment: check this link https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

Comment: Use search anywhere in Android Studio (Double shift) and search for the xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Perform **Go To File** <kbd>Cmd + Shift + O</kbd>
- Fill in the resource name
- Check *Include non-project files* checkbox if needed

[image]